# How to loop through a json in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this PHP equivalent in javascript.

How can I do the same loop I did with PHP in javascript?

Comment: "a json" … sorry, I laughed to myself

Comment: This question has been stripped of all its original context. In its current state it is not suitable anymore as SO posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop through json in javascript like:

```
for(key in json){
    console.log(key,json[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the basic syntax of looping wrong:

```
  for (json.messages in object){
    alert(object.message);
  }
```

Assuming that you want to loop the messages in `json.messages`, and using a name other than `object` as that might be a system built-in, you would actually write it as follows:

```
  for (alertMessage in json.messages){
    alert(alertMessage);
  }
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

you got basically the position of variable and array wrong: variable comes left side of the `in`.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through JSON in JavaScript, use a `for ... in ...` loop like this:

```js
var json = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');

for (key in json) {
  console.log(key + ": " + json[key]);
}
```